# What's the easiest way to create a TAlphaColor from RGB values?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

What's the easiest way to create a `TAlphaColor` from individual R,G,B integer values?

I know of two ways. In the following, assume `r`,`g`,`b` are integers 0->255:

```
rec : TAlphaColorRec
color : TAlphaColor;

rec.A := 255;
rec.R := r;
rec.B := b;
rec.G := g;
color := rec.Color;
```

```
color := TAlphaColorF.Create(r/255, g/255, b/255).ToAlphaColor;
```

The former seems verbose, and the later overkill. I thought there might have been a function such as the following, but there doesn't appear to be:

```
color = TAlphaColor.RGBToColor (r,g,b,1)
```

Are there any other ways to create `TAlphaColor` from R,G,B values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is basically it.  However, you don't need a separate `TAlphaColorRec` variable, you can type-cast the `TAlphaColor` variable to access its components, eg:

```
var color : TAlphaColor;
TAlphaColorRec(color).A := 255;
TAlphaColorRec(color).R := r;
TAlphaColorRec(color).B := b;
TAlphaColorRec(color).G := g;
```

This is exactly what `TAlphaColorF.ToAlphaColor` does internally for its `Result`:

```
function TAlphaColorF.ToAlphaColor: TAlphaColor;
begin
  TAlphaColorRec(Result).R := Round(R * 255);
  TAlphaColorRec(Result).G := Round(G * 255);
  TAlphaColorRec(Result).B := Round(B * 255);
  TAlphaColorRec(Result).A := Round(A * 255);
end;
```